# Unable to encode an asset with two videos in azure media services v3

Tags: azure, video-encoding, azure-media-services

I am capturing multiple videos and trying to store them all in one media asset and later encode them. But I always get the below error. There are no issues however if I upload one file to asset and run the encoding job.

Output 'BuiltInStandardEncoderPreset_0', Error : Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media.Models.JobError : While trying to download the input files, the files were not accessible, please check the availability of the source.

Do I need to use one media asset for each upload? Is having multiple files in one asset not the right approach?

FYI: I tried all thesew steps on media servicer explorer desktop app. So please be sure I didn't write any code for this.

Comment: Do you need further help?

Answer (score 2):

You would indeed need to use a separate Asset for each video. We'll follow up with a service update to improve the error message in this situation.

Comment: Yeah, that would be helpful. So I read in the documentation that there is a limit
Assets per Media Services account (1,000,000). I am afraid in production we might hit this limit in production as we are capturing a larger number of short videos. I know this is number is not fixed and can be requested to increase. Is it easy to do so?

Comment: If you expect to hit larger Asset counts when your service is in production, then please open a support ticket via Azure Portal - the support engineers will guide you on the next steps.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is not the upload of multiple files in one asset, but the fact that the encoding job will not pick each blob of the asset and encoding them. That's why you need to use one asset per video file to be encoded.